# What is the _qualitative_ difference between re.findall and an iterative re.search?

Tags: python, regex

When one wants to find and process all occurrences of a regex in a string, what is the *qualitative* difference between `re.findall` and iterating over its returned list versus iterating directly with `re.search`?

In code, what is the qualitative difference between the `findall` version:

```
sbls = "some big ... long string"
for i in some_regex.findall( sbls )
    process_item( i )
```

And the iterative `search` version:

```
sbls = "some big ... long string"
m = some_regex.search( sbls )
while m:
    process_item( m.group() )
    m = some_regex.search(sbls, m.end())
```

In a **very** large string and a poorly chosen/low-cardinality regex, would the `findall` version consume more memory (perhaps via the list)?  Conversely, would the `search` version take noticeably more time?

Up to the constraints of the hardware to which I have access, I have not been able to discern a non-negligible difference, so would much appreciate others' insights.

Comment: With `finditer()` you have access to different groups (sic!) while iterating only once. This one follows somewhat the generator concetp of `Python`. Thus, it is less memory intensive. With small to medium string sizes this might only have differences in milliseconds though.

Comment: How did I miss this!?  I swear I search for iteration in the documentation before posting.  Well, thanks @Jan for pointing it out.  Sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Jan says, find all is marginally faster, however the later gives you finer control over what to do with each match, eg perhaps you find what you want early you can break and save the effort of finding the remaining matches.